# Access array value in JSON directly without loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "params":{
      "facet":"true",
      "fl":"city",
      "facet.mincount":"1",
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"0",
      "q":["*:*",
        "*:*"],
      "wt":"json",
      "rows":"12"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {"city":"lathum"}]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_fields":{
      "hasphoto":[
        "true",61,
        "false",5],
      "hasvideo":[
        "false",51,
        "true",15],
      "rating_rounded":[
        "0.0",62,
        "10.0",3,
        "8.0",1]},
    "facet_ranges":{}}}
```

I wonder if it's possible to select a value based on a property name, in my case, I want to select how many of `hasphoto` have the value `true`, which would be 61.
Please note that the `true` value does not necessarily have to be the first listed under hasphoto, `true` and `false` are sorted by number of occurences.

I want to get the value directly without having to loop through it....is that possible?

I tried:

```
response.facet_counts.facet_fields['hasphoto']['true']
```

and

```
response.facet_counts.facet_fields.hasphoto['true']
```

But both return `undefined`.

Comment: You should probably indicate what language you're using.  JSON support in FORTRAN is pretty arcane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are ordered lists, not key-value stores so

`response.facet_counts.facet_fields.hasphoto[0]` gives you the string "true",
`response.facet_counts.facet_fields.hasphoto[1]` gives you the number 61,
etc...

Comment: Hmmm, ok, so I tried `inArray` this `console.log('index of true:' + $.inArray('true', data.facet_counts.facet_fields['hasphoto']));` but that returns `2`...do you know why?